# mysql error in xampp - ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'photo' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, xampp

[image]

When I am trying to insert values, mysql doesn't allow to add empty values. How to solve this. I couldn't find my.cnf file edit the STRICT mode even. SO can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: You do not fill the `photo` column. Because the table needs a value since it is defined as NOT NULL and has no default value to fill it automatically.

Comment: Then it will generate an error as 2nd image. I have assigned 0000-00-00 as end date

Comment: If some column can be NULL then why not just define them to allow NULL?

Comment: I also have the same question. May be that column type is date. How can I solve it?

Comment: just a bit curious, how does you set the date in the second error screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get sql_mode value from mysql using this command

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

If you get value which contains  STRICT_TRANS_TABLES then you have to remove it from gobal parameter otherwise you will get this message each time when you will not pass any value to filed. This global setting by default provided from mysql version 5.6. To change the value run this to mysql

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

This will set to null and will allow to run your query.

Comment: Not that is STRICT_TRANS_TABLES as the output. It will return NO..ENGINE.. something. Then after running the SET Global sql_mode query, it will generate @@global.sql_mode as the output. Next when I'm trying to run the site and trying to insert values then same error appears as in the second picture